# Edge selection - cannot select

Tags: modeling

I want to move a vertex, not duplicate. But I cannot select the vertex with its connected edges, only the vertex

Here is the file: [image]

Try moving the vertex and please find out why its doing this.

[image]

Comment: Could you be more precise? You cannot select or cannnot extend? What is slightly darker? It can also be useful to add link to related questions if they provide infomation about the scene

Comment: Question is unprecise and should improve it's clarity as to what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: i think the questioner means that he/she wants to extrude/move a vertex, not duplicate, but he/she cannot select the vertex with its connected edges, only the vertex

Comment: Faceb Faceb. You are right. I'm sorry and I know that this question is confusing. But it was it really hard to explain

Comment: Have you tried switching to Edge Select mode? (Ctrl+Tab)

Comment: @Mooneon, may I suggest packing the image into your ~.blend file (using File > external data > Pack all into Blend), and uploading a copy of that Blend file to [Blend exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: @brasshat that will be suitable, yes I will do that.

Comment: @Mooneon, are you referring to the fact that in edit mode, when one selects a vertex, one usually sees the adjacent portion of the edges of which the vertex is a part colored orange? If so, then apparently for some reason, when there is a mirror modifier applied to a mesh, this capability is suppressed. If I block expression of, or remove the mirror modifier, the adjacent portions of the edges including the selected vertex are displayed again. I'm not well enough informed on the mirror modifier to know why it is implemented in this way, or how to change the behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple really. You have 2 vertices on the same spot. You may have accidentally duplicate the vertices while you were working on it. Good news is that it's really easy to solve.

1. While you are in Edit Mode. Hit <kbd>W</kbd>
2. Look for the option "Remove Double" in the drop down list.
3. Now try moving the vertex again.

You should have no problems!